# Sending data from form to php file using post method

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to send sent and id values from form.php to test.php. Without ajax use it works fine. I am learning ajax and here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
    if (str=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax_test.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send(sent&id);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    Enter the sentence: <input type="text" name="sent"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="insert" onclick="showUser(this.value)"/>
</form>
</br>
UPDATE </br>
<form action="ajax_test.php" method="post"/>
    <pre>
        Enter the ID : <input type="text" name="id"/><br/>
        Enter the sentence: <input type="text" name="sent"/><br/>
    </pre>
    <input type="submit" name="update"/>
</form>
</br>
<form>
    <input type="submit" onclick="showUser(this.value)"/>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint">
    <b>Person info will be listed here.</b>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

ajax_test.php is here:

```
<html> <body > 
<?php
$q = $_GET["q"];
if (!empty($_POST['insert']))
{
    echo "Operation: Insert";
    echo "<br/>";

    $s    = $_POST['sent'];
    $flag = 0;

    echo "Entered sentence : $s";

    if (preg_match_all('/[^=]*=([^;@]*)/', 
        shell_exec("/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/client '$s'"),
        $matches)) //Values stored in ma.
    {
        $x = (int) $matches[1][0]; //optionally cast to int
        $y = (int) $matches[1][1];
    }

    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Positive count :$x";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Negative count :$y";
    echo "<br/>";

    //---------------DB stuff --------------------
    $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3306', 'root', 'root', 'test');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO table2 
             (id,sent,pcount,ncount,flag)
             VALUES
             ('','$_POST[sent]','" . $x . "','" . $y . "','" . $flag . "')";
    if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql1)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    echo "1 record added";
    mysqli_close($con);
}

// -------------------------------UPDATE --------------------------
if (!empty($_POST['update']))
{
    echo "Operation: update";
    echo "<br/>";

    $s    = $_POST['sent'];
    $flag = 1;

    echo "Entered sentence : $s";

    if (preg_match_all('/[^=]*=([^;@]*)/', 
        shell_exec("/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/client '$s'"),
        $matches)) //Values stored in ma.
    {
        $x = (int) $matches[1][0]; //optionally cast to int
        $y = (int) $matches[1][1];
    }

    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Positive count :$x";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Negative count :$y";
    echo "<br/>";

    //---------------DB stuff --------------------
    $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3306', 'root', 'root', 'test');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO table2 
             (id,sent,pcount,ncount,flag)
             VALUES
             ('$_POST[id]','$_POST[sent]','" . $x . "','" . $y . "','" . $flag . "')";
    if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql1)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    echo "1 record added";
    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
</html > </body >
```

When I click the button it shows nothing. How can I sent id and sent values so that I can use it on ajax_test.php the I am using?

Comment: Have you used the developer tools in your browser to check for any javascript errors?

Comment: You can also use firebug or similar browser developer tool to verify what is being sent such as if your parameters are being passed down the right way etc.

Comment: I would recommend that usaes `jQuery` for sending variables [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and `Firebug` to track what happens. Look [this example](http://www.jensbits.com/2009/10/04/jquery-ajax-and-jquery-post-form-submit-examples-with-php/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code: 
`Context-type` was missing and some other changes!

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showUser(form, e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue=false;
        var xmlhttp;
        var submit = form.getElementsByClassName('submit')[0];
        var sent = form.elements['sent'].value;
    var id = form.elements['id'].value;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open(form.method, form.action, true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
        xmlhttp.send('sent=' + sent + '&id=' + id + '&' + submit.name + '=' + submit.value);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>INSERT</h4>
    <form action="ajax_test.php" method="POST" onsubmit="showUser(this, event)">
        <pre>
             <label>Enter the sentence: <input type="text" name="sent"></label><br/>
        </pre>
                <input type="submit" class="submit" name="insert" value="submit"/>
        <input type="" name="id" style="display: none"/>
    </form>

    <h4>UPDATE</h4>
    <form action="ajax_test.php" method="POST" onsubmit="showUser(this, event)">
        <pre>
            <label>Enter the ID:        </label><input type="text" name="id"><br>
            <label>Enter the sentence:  <input type="text" name="sent"></label><br />
        </pre>
        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="submit" name="update"/>
    </form>

    <br />
    <div id="txtHint">
        <b>Person info will be listed here.</b>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

with the ajax method being `post` this is invalid

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax_test.php?q="+str,true);
```

instead it should be

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax_test.php",true);
xmlhttp.send('q='+str);
```

you should not put the request string in the url unless you are using the `GET` method

to prevent the form from sending and going to the action page on click, you need to use `preventDefault()` function like so in your javascript and you should also initialize the var `xmlhttp` at the top of the function.

```
function showUser(str, e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var xmlhttp;
```

and in the html `onclick="showUser(this.value, event)"`

below is a short term fix to this solution but i strongly recommend you read more on javascript, html and php syntax as long as best practices

```
<script>
function showUser(form, e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var xmlhttp;
 var submit = form.getElementsByClassName('submit')[0];
 var sent = form.getElementsByName('sent')[0].value || '';
 var id = form.getElementsByName('id')[0].value || '';


if (sent==""){
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
}

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(e) {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open(form.method, form.action, true);
xmlhttp.send('sent='+sent+'&id='+id+'&'+submit.name+'='+submit.value);
}
</script>
<form action="ajax_test.php" method="POST" onsubmit="showUser(this, event)">
Enter the sentence: <input type="text" name="sent"><br>
<input type="submit" class="submit" name="insert" value="submit" >
</form>
<br>UPDATE <br>
 <form action="ajax_test.php" method="POST" onsubmit="showUser(this, event)">
<pre>
    Enter the ID : <input type="text" name="id"><br>
    Enter the sentence: <input type="text" name="sent"><br>
</pre>
 <input type="submit" class="submit" value="submit" name="update">
</form> <br>
<div id="txtHint">
 <b>Person info will be listed here.</b>
 </div>
```

you don't need to add a closing slash to `<br>` br or `<input>` input tags unless you are using a strict markup like xhtml.

in your ajax_test.php document remove the `<html>` and `<body>` tags so it can be processed properly by ajax. don't worry its not going to affect how your page will render if the page was called without an ajax call, the browser automatically puts those tags in when page is reached unless its already present.

change ajax_test.php

```
<?php
// $q = $_POST["q"];
// you never process the $q var so i commented it
if (isset($_POST['insert']) && $_POST['insert'] !== '') {
echo "Operation: Insert","<br>";

$s = $_POST['sent'];
$flag = 0;

echo "Entered sentence : $s";

if (preg_match_all('/[^=]*=([^;@]*)/', 
    shell_exec("/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/client '$s'"),
    $matches)){ //Values stored in ma. 
    $x = (int) $matches[1][0]; //optionally cast to int
    $y = (int) $matches[1][1];
}

echo "<br>",
     "Positive count :$x",
     "<br>",
     "Negative count :$y",
     "<br>";

//---------------DB stuff --------------------
$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3306', 'root', 'root', 'test');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO table2 
         (id,sent,pcount,ncount,flag)
         VALUES
         ('".$_POST['id']."','".$_POST['sent']."',' $x ','$y','$flag')";
if (mysqli_query($con, $sql1)) {
   echo "1 record added";
} else {
   die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}


mysqli_close($con);
}

// -------------------------------UPDATE --------------------------
 if (isset($_POST['update']) && $_POST['update'] !== '') {
echo "Operation: update", "<br>";
 // you say update but you are actually inserting below

$s    = $_POST['sent'];
$flag = 1;

echo "Entered sentence : $s";

if (preg_match_all('/[^=]*=([^;@]*)/', 
    shell_exec("/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/client '$s'"),
    $matches)) //Values stored in ma.
{
    $x = (int) $matches[1][0]; //optionally cast to int
    $y = (int) $matches[1][1];
}

echo "<br>",
     "Positive count :$x",
     "<br>",
     "Negative count :$y",
     "<br>";

//---------------DB stuff --------------------
$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3306', 'root', 'root', 'test');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO table2 
         (id,sent,pcount,ncount,flag)
         VALUES
         ('".$_POST['id']."','".$_POST['sent']."',' $x ','$y','$flag')"; // error here again $_POST[id] should be $_POST['id'] with quotes
if (mysqli_query($con, $sql1)) {
  echo "1 record added";
} else { 
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

 mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

there are a lot of errors here man, i tried to correcting them all but i can't test it and  like i said you should read up on best practices because your code and syntax is pretty bad no to be harsh.

**EDIT**

further explanation on `preventDefault`:

we use this function to prevent the default form submission actions, which is sending the form by relocating the browser to the action page `action="ajax_test.php"` and setting parameters in the background or for `GET` methods in the url.

then after that you'll still want to send the form in and thats where ajax comes in;
  we use ajax to send forms asynchronously and without browser relocation.  we can just load the page inside of the ajax call and process the response from the paged called inside of javascript `xmlhttp.responseText`.

Comment: Also, you may want to return false to stop the browser from following the link, defeating the purpose of using ajax.

Comment: @Jay: `xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax_test.php?q="+sent&id,true);` is it correct way to send two parameters at ajax_test.php? and on ajax_test way we receive the values `$s    = $_POST['sent'];`will remain same I believe if I am not false!

Comment: @Karimkhan you can not put the query string in the open funtion for post calls, i edited the answer to show how to do so correctly

Comment: @jayharris: It was really very well explained! I read the documentation of preventDefault which says `Prevent a submit button from submitting a form`. Ans also as you said it stops from sending on click. But i am really confused. Ultimately our purpose is to send data to ajax_test.php on button click, so why we need to stop sending? Did I understand in wrong way?

Comment: @Karimkhan i apologize for the confusion, it prevents the form from sending a form and going the page specified in the action attribute. the ajax call will send the form without going the page

Comment: @jayharris: Thanks a lot for clear exlaination dear! But after making the changes you told, still it does not work. Does it require any other change? Please dont leave this, after few correction I could make your answer selected1

Comment: @Catty though i can't test it myself, i can point out some things with your script. you flip flop on methods in your ajax_test.php page, try yours $_REQUEST instead of switch between $_POST and $_GET

Comment: you have a floating form that takes no input other than the submit button

Comment: @jayharris: Yes you right, On button click it does not event make call to ajax_test.php! Really sad! I would really happy and thankful if you can tell me what you mean by floating form!

Comment: @Catty this is the floating form that seems to serve no purpose `<form> <input type="submit" onclick="showUser(this.value)"/> </form>` . further more on your errors, what is your error ? what is your javascript console saying? what is beign returned in the html after the ajax call?

Comment: @jayharris: After button click, it show nothing on the page! no event takes place. Even echo msg written on ajax_test.php also does not appear. I think it's not successfully making call to ajax_test.php!

Comment: @jayharris: Here call to function showUser() is being made in form? Should we place it like : `<input type="submit" class="submit" name="insert" value="submit" onsubmit="showUser(this, event)">`